# Changing Array Formatting

Tags: jquery, arrays, formatting

I have a two-dimensional array that is formatted as followed:

```
[["a",1], ["b",2]]
```

I want to change its formatting to this:

```
{"a":1,"b":2}
```

How can I do this?  Sorry if it is an easy/stupid question.

Comment: Wow, this question turned into "who can post this code the fastest"!

Comment: Hahaha I know.  Free karma!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume you're sure that the same key won't appear twice (i.e., there won't be two inner arrays with `"a"`):

```
var inputArray = [["a",1], ["b",2]],
    outputObject = {},
    i;

for (i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
    outputObject[inputArray[i][0]] = inputArray[i][1];
```

If that's not enough jQuery for you then I guess you can use `$.each()` instead of a `for` loop, etc., but in my opinion a plain `for` loop is fine for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [["a",1], ["b",2]], obj = {}, i;

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    obj[arr[i][0]] = arr[i][1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy:

```
var myList = {};
for( var i in myArray ) {
    myList[myArray[i][0]] = myArray[i][1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = {};
$.each([["a",1], ["b", 2]], function(){result[this[0]] = this[1]})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the multidimensional array, assigning the inner arrays first index as the property and the second as the value.

```
var arr = [["a",1], ["b",2]];
var obj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  obj[arr[i][0]] = arr[i][1];
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/4Pmzx/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the key won't appear twice:

```
var o = {};
[["a",1], ["b",2]].forEach(function(value) {o[value[0]] = value[1];});
```